# Way to reproduce this layout effect with css?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Short of creating a 7 column / 3 row table with a 1 pixel image that can be expanded to simulate the lines, how can this layout be reproduced using HTML and CSS without a table or an image for the "dividers"?

What I really like about it is how the lines don't intersect.

[image]

```html
<!-- layout reproduced -->
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
    <TR ALIGN="center">
        <TD CLASS="boldedcolor4text">the first</TD>
        <TD><IMG SRC="/gfx/Style1/color1.gif" ALT="" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="20"></TD>
        <TD CLASS="boldedcolor4text">the second</TD>
        <TD><IMG SRC="/gfx/Style1/color1.gif" ALT="" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="20"></TD>
        <TD CLASS="boldedcolor4text">the third</TD>
        <TD><IMG SRC="/gfx/Style1/color1.gif" ALT="" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="20"></TD>
        <TD CLASS="boldedcolor4text">the fourth</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN="center">
        <TD COLSPAN="7"><IMG SRC="/gfx/Style1/color1.gif" ALT="" WIDTH="520" HEIGHT="1"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN="center">
        <TD><A CLASS="image" HREF="><IMG SRC="1.jpg" ALT="" BORDER="0"></A></TD>
        <TD><IMG SRC="/gfx/Style1/color1.gif" ALT="" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="135"></TD>
        <TD><A CLASS="image" HREF="><IMG SRC="2.jpg" ALT="" BORDER="0"></A></TD>
        <TD><IMG SRC="/gfx/Style1/color1.gif" ALT="" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="135"></TD>
        <TD><A CLASS="image" HREF="><IMG SRC="3.jpg" ALT="" BORDER="0"></A></TD>
        <TD><IMG SRC="/gfx/Style1/color1.gif" ALT="" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="135"></TD>
        <TD><A CLASS="image" HREF="><IMG SRC="4.jpg" ALT="" BORDER="0"></A></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a table here? To me, this looks like tabular data, and thus, and html `table` should be the appropriate construct here, especially from a semantic point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it like: https://jsfiddle.net/wh48rjvt/

SCSS:

```
$border: 1px solid grey;
.table-row {
  border-bottom: $border;
  &:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .table-box {
    border-right: $border;
    margin: 0.75rem 0;
    &:last-child {
      border-right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

this makes following CSS:

```
.table-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
.table-row:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.table-row .table-box {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0.75rem 0;
}
.table-row .table-box:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-row row">
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">1</div>
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">2</div>
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row row">
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">5</div>
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">6</div>
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">7</div>
    <div class="table-box col-xs-3">8</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

And I used Bootstrap for the grid.

Comment: Thanks for this! That's awesome and you've taught me a lot of new things as I had no idea what SCSS was until your solution. I like it because on the surface at least it's simpler. Now I need to do some reading on SCSS to figure out exactly is happening with what you've provided. The only downfall to this answer, which I guess can't really be done non-dynamically, is when the browser window gets too small to automatically have it wrap and adjust the dividing lines as appropriate. Otherwise, I like it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Try to copy the SCSS code into a online compiler like http://www.sassmeister.com/, there you will see the output and understand what happens there ;-)

Answer (score 10):

No dependencies for my solution. I create a flexbox `.container` and then four flex `.item`s. The default direction for flexbox is `row`, which is what we want for the outer layout, but not for the contents of each item in the row. To adjust this, I changed the `flex-direction` of the children (`.item`) to `column` since, in your example, the images are stacked beneath the anchors.

For the non-breaking border between the anchors and the images, I took a bit of a shortcut and moved the styles to a pseudo class. Notice the `position: relative;` on `.item`. This was done to create a safe container in which to *hold* the absolutely positioned pseudo class borders.

```css
.container, .item {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.item:before {
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 2em;
}

.item:first-child:before {
  left: 1.5em;
}

.item:last-child:before {
  left: -1.5em;
}

.item:last-child .link,
.item:last-child .img {
  border-right: none;
}

.link,
.img {
  border-right: 1px solid;  
}

.link {
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <a class="link" href="">link 1</a>
    <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/100x130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a class="link" href="">link 2</a>
    <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/100x130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a class="link" href="">link 3</a>
    <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/100x130" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a class="link" href="">link 4</a>
    <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/100x130" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1sbx2h5e/

Comment: Wow! What a solution. Thanks for this! I wish I could mark two answers as the "answer", but chose the one by @Sergej because there's less complex CSS (although I don't know half of what he's doing yet -- new research project! :-) ).